# c++ list not resizing after set difference

Tags: c++, set-difference

Consider the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> v = {1, 3, 4};
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
    v.resize(0);
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

after compiling the output, as expected, is

```
3
0
```

Now I add a set difference.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
    std::list<int> x = {1, 3, 4};
    std::list<int> y = {1, 2, 3, 5};
    std::list<int> v;
    x.sort();
    y.sort();
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
    auto it =
        std::set_difference(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), v.begin());
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
    v.resize(0);
    std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

and the output is

```
0
4
4
```

why does the resize work for the first example, but not in the second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because it is undefined behavior.

The last parameter to `std::set_difference` is an output iterator. You are passing in `v.begin()`.

This returns a pointer to the beginning of an empty list. In order for your intended code to work as advertised, the `*iter++` operation of the output iterator ***must add new values to the list***.

Unfortunately, no matter what you do with the iterator that's returned by `begin()`, nothing that you do to it will make the list any bigger or smaller than it already is. It is just iterating over the ***existing contents*** of the list.

At this point, you're pretty much in undefined behavior territory, and any results you get will be completely nonsensical (if not an immediate crash).

Instead of passing in `v.begin()`, you need to [use `std::back_insert_iterator` instead](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator).

Comment: There is `std::back_inserter` which simplifies using `std::back_insert_iterator`. You can replace `v.begin()` with `std::back_inserter(v)`.

Comment: Very well explained by @Sam, Also if you don't want to use back_insert_iterator, you can give size of `v` while initializing, maximum of which can be the size of x, so to be on the safe side you can initialize as `std::list<int> v(x.size());` though it's a waste of memory.